# How do I match a name with a possible special character using regex and Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to match names like John Williams and Kevin O'McDonald-Smith, but not Kevin O''McDonald, Kevin O'McDonald-Smith-Williams, or Kevin Smith John Smith. My attempted code is below:

```
r1 = re.findall(r"(([A-z]+')?[A-z]+)([,]?[\s-](([A-z]+')?[A-z]+)){0,2}", "Kevin O'McDonald-Smith")
print(r1)
```

This outputs:

```
[('Kevin', '', '-Smith', 'Smith', "O'")]
```

I'm expecting:

```
[("Kevin O'McDonald-Smith")]
```

I've tested this regex case on https://regexr.com/ , but my code using Python's `re` library is giving an output that I am not expecting.

Comment: re.findall() return a tuple in your case and scan from left to right `If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.`

Comment: [falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest way to enforce this would be to use a negative lookahead assertion which enforces that no more than one special character appear inside the name:

```
name = "Kevin O'McDonald-Smith-Williams"
if re.search(r'^(?!.*[\'-].*[\'-]).*$', name):
    print("MATCH")
else:
    print("NO MATCH")
```

This prints: `NO MATCH`

The negative lookahead `(?!.*[\'-].*[\'-])` asserts that two (or more) special characters do not appear in the name.  One special character would still be allowed, as would any other character, including space.